# axVLCPlugin(VideoLAN) faster state to normal state

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, c#-3.0, activex

I am using axVLCPlugin to play video in windows application.I am using axVLCPlugin.playFaster(); to play faster.But after that it is not coming back to the normal play mode by any means.Can anyone suggest?

Comment: IMO it's an old bug in VLC MP, I've encountered it on each video I played, have you tried playSlower()? the normal Play button didn't work as it should

Answer (score 1):

Video speed can be increased or decreased by setting the value of vlc.input.rate.
if vlc.input.rate = 1 then normal speed.
vlc.input.rate > 1 then increases speed.

Answer (score 0):

Well it work's perfect if you change `vlc.input.rate` ,it multiplies normal rate with Rate adjusted at this Property.

I recommend increasing it at Maximum 10 otherwise it might crash and/or lose Seek feature.

Comment: I am using C# based using activeX control. I am unable to see above mentioned properly. Can you please let me know what is appropriate property I can use with VLCPlugin ActiveX control in C#?

Comment: Maybe you're using the wrong plugin Version ,you should use Plugin Version2 because at Toolbox you can find 2 Version's @AnindyaChatterjee